# PyQt ListView with groups

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

How can i create connection groups inside a QListView with PyQt.

The group name should not be selectable.

Example: http://www.shrani.si/f/T/bB/gSpSsYt/connectionlist.jpg :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two approaches: add items that are the "section headings" that can be set disabled (see `setFlags`), or use a `QTreeView`.